# Passing Configuration and Initializing a Client in Azure Functions w/ Dependency Injection

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I'm creating a new `Azure Functions` with a `Queue` trigger. A key requirement is for me to use my existing class libraries that I created in my `ASP.NET Core` app so that I can access my `Repository` methods. I also have my own clients that handle communication with some third party services.

I need help with creating instances of my clients and passing configuration to them which is `IConfiguration`.

Here's what my `Startup.cs` looks like in my `Azure Functions` project:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MyApp.Infrastructure.Clients;
using MyApp.Infrastructure.Interface;
using MyApp.Infrastructure.Repositories;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyTestFunction.Startup))]
namespace MyTestFunction
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(new MyApp.Infrastructure.Clients.MyClient123(Configuration));
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ICommunicationsRepository, CommunicationsRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

In my `ASP.NET Core` app's `Startup.cs`, I do have a `constructor` that handles the configuration -- see below -- but not sure how to handle this `Azure Functions`.

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
     Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is not a recommended approach:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4464#issuecomment-513017446

I've decided to update my class libraries in my `ASP.NET Core` app so that I use `Azure KeyVault` in both my `API` and `Azure Functions` apps.